# Is it possible to have a plane with its normal as reference for Transform Orientation

Tags: transforms, normals

Is it possible to have a plane with its normal as reference for *Transform Orientation* (Global, Local, Normal, Gimbal, View axis)? For example, I would like to select every face and scale to 0 to the normal Z-axis:
[image]

But if I select every face then this normal Z-axis changes:
[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Space to create a transformation orientation aligned to the face then select all and S, Z, Z, 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [custom transform orientations](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations/). The shortcut is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> or in the properties sidebar in the Tranform Orientations panel you will find a small `+` that will create a new orientation based on the current selection, in this panel you can also rename and delete any custom transforms you have created.

Once you have defined a custom transform you can activate it in the transform orientation menu so that your transform manipulator is oriented the way you want.

[image]