# Axis problem between a parent - child relationship

Tags: modeling

Hello blender community!

Just a question about a problem I have with axis of a child object.
It's two planes attach by a parent link to a cylinder. 
Cylinder is the parent, the two planes are its child.

When I want to reduce one of my 3D plane (on the left) by moving his different faces in a perpendicular fashion, I can t find the perfect perpendicular axis (even with normal or local), because the center of "gravity" mix the one of the plane and the one of the cylinder...

After Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C, and "origin to geometry" when I selected the plane alone, It's still a problem...

[image]
[image]

And of course, if I remove the relationship between the plane and the cylinder by Alt+P the plane return on its original position (witch is far away ^^) and I lose its position information, even if I lock the location X/Y/Z in transform table...

[image]
[image]

So:

1) Is it possible to **keep the position** of the child object when you remove the relationship parent - child? Like that I will be able to have a good local axis of the plane.

2) Or do you have a solution to force the local axis of my plane to be as usual without noticing his relationship with the cylinder?

Thank you very much for your help +++

I'm giving you the file to help.
The plane goes in an other direction after Alt + P because  of the rotation I have performed with an armature before I made it the child of the cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a copy of your blend ? I tried to make something similar and couldn't reproduce the problem - everything worked well (with Global or Normal axis used, depending on the case)

Comment: The local spaces of the planes should stay normal, what you probably did was transform the planes in edit mode. For the manipulator problem go into the plane's edit mode, select the face, save the transforms orientation (http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33320/7777) and choose this orientation in object mode to have it.

Comment: IT'S WORKING! thx Jerryno!