# Accidentally applied rotation and its to late to undo

Tags: transforms

So I accidentally applied the rotation of an arm and its to late to undo. Is there a way to fix this accurately?
[image]

Comment: There's no way to "fix" that. You have possibility to use Normal transform orientation, [create custom transform orientation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33294/is-it-possible-to-have-a-plane-with-its-normal-as-reference-for-transform-orient) or [align view with face](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal) and then transform according to View transform orientation.

Comment: maybe you can align/rotate another simple object to the arm, then use a "copy rotation" constraint on the arm to copy its rotation, but with "invert", then use "apply > visual transforms"... then apply rotation... I tried on a simple shape... it depends on your specific case though...

Comment: Also rotating the vertices by snapping active vertex to a reference point can yield good results although it will only be 99,999% perfect. Afterwards you can try to find a small enough zoom level in ortho view so you can snap the vertices to grid.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the "Geometry" orientation with the cursor tool,

[image: 1]

and the "Affect Only Origins" option selected.

[image: 2]

Here's an object with its rotation applied, click on the face you want reset to the correct position with the cursor tool, in this case it would be the top face.

[image: 3]

Now, Shift-S > Cursor to Selected (make sure the object you want to reset is selected) - This will make sure the position transformations stay the same and only rotation origins are changed

[image: 4]

Finally, make sure your transform orientation is set to "Cursor" and go to Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

You should now see that your applied rotation has been fixed, and if you set the rotate values back to 0 the object will be pointed perfectly up. Don't forget to disable "Affect Only Origins" so you are able to transform your object again.

[image: 7]