# How do you Undo applied rotation?

Tags: origin

I've rotated a cube on Y, Applied rotation.
Now the Origins Local rotation is the same as global.
Not knowing the cube rotation on Y how do you "Exactly" set the Origins rotation back to the object's local orientation?
Hand rotating is not the answer.

[image: local origin orintation]

[image: Applied rotation]

Comment: Hello :). One dirty solution: Duplicate the object and snap it to a flat surface. That will give you the precise rotation needed.

Comment: Maybe this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8897/55344 It's a little old but I think it should still work.

Comment: This should be the answer to your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290108/165212